# Inserting form data into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

**This is starting to wind me up.. I've started building the PHP for the register page but none of the inputted data is inserting into the database.**

I know the inputs aren't secure, it's just completely basic as i stripped it down completely and now this isn't even working. I'm not getting any errors in my log, and there is a connection to the database.

All the data from the form is echoing out, just to make sure it recognises the input fields, but it's really starting to wind me up... And also, I'm not using a later version of PHP, reason why I'm not using mysqli_query instead of mysql_query.

```
session_start();
include_once "settings/conf.php";
  if(isset($_POST['join'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joinData, contributor)
VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email','$date'0)");
echo 'Ok.';
}
```

Please, can somebody help me!

**Much appreciated!**

Comment: -1 for the title

Comment: Did you actually connect to the DB? And please do not use any `mysql_*` functions and go for mysqli or PDO

Comment: when you say "using `mysql` instead of `mysqli` because of your PHP version.... uh, what PHP version are you using -- because `mysqli` has been available for a *very* long time (as has PDO for that matter). If you're using a version old enough not to have `mysqli`, then you are in serious trouble.

Comment: If you actually read it, I said I'm using an old version of php... haven't got round to upgrading, that's why I can't use mysqli.

Comment: SQL syntax error at the end of the query -- what is that zero doing there? and why is it not separated from the date field with a comma?

Comment: mysqli can be used with PHP 5+ and Mysql 4.1.3+. You should consider upgrading. Personal note: I prefer PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, in your query it looks like (at the position of the $date variable) you missed  a comma, this is required to separate those 5 values. This probably solves the issue.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joinData, contributor)
VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email','$date',0)");
```

If it still won't work:

- Have you tried to print those values from the POST methods
  on the page to see if they even come through?
- Then,  are you sure you've set the method to POST in your form?

Comment: Never mind, thanks for the input, rookie error, miss spelt joinData.. it's joinDate.. Been awake for 36 hours, i'm normally great lol.

Comment: I'm glad it works now! I know, programming is awesome. Btw, it would be great if you could mark my post as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joinData, contributor) VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email','$date'0)");
```

You are missing here a comma before the zero:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joinData, contributor) VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email','$date', 0)");
THERE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry.. even with the comma it's not inserting.

Comment: @JakeDuncan Then borrow me your magic wand; It's the single thing wrong in your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering/sanitizing all your $_POST data before entering into your DB?

Answer (score 0):

you missing a comma in between date and 0

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joinData, contributor)
VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email','$date',0)");
echo 'Ok.';
}
```